# Microsoft Teams Authentication

Tags: authentication, oauth, callback, tabs, microsoft-teams

I've developed a custom Teams app, it has one base tab where the user must log in before viewing some content.
The auth is over Oauth2 code flow, using an external npm package (@openid/appauth).
I've create this code for open the popUp when user make a click into login button:

```js
     login = () => {
            const successCallback = (result) => {
                this.props.setLogged(result);
            }
            const failureCallback = (error) => {
                logger.warn(JSON.stringify(error));
                this.props.setError(error);
            }
            authClient.teamsAuthRequest(this.props.user.PartitionKey, this.props.user.RowKey, successCallback, failureCallback);
        }
```

this function: teamsAuthRequest is only the configuration used for make call to the authorization endpoint:

```js
     teamsAuthRequest: async (tid, aaId, successCallback, failureCallback) => {
                const config = await createConfiguration();
                const request = createAuthRequest(tid, aaId);
                teamsHandler.performAuthorizationRequest(config, request, successCallback, failureCallback);
            }
```

It call a function that open the popUp by this code:

```js
            microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate({
                url: url,
                width: 600,
                height: 550,
                successCallback: function (result) {
                    successCallback(result);
                },
                failureCallback: function (reason) {
                    failureCallback(reason)
                }
            });
```

If I use teams web it correctly opens the popup and close it after login.

If I use the same app into teams desktop, it correctly opens the popup but it never calls the notifySuccess function and it never close the popup.

When I receive the callback from the external provider to receive the authorization code I run this code:

```js
      if (response) {
        authClient.getToken(request && request.internal && request.internal.code_verifier, response.code)
          .then((oResponse) => {
            user = {
              PartitionKey: request.extras.tid,
              RowKey: request.extras.aaId,
              AccessToken: oResponse.accessToken,
              RefreshToken: oResponse.refreshToken
            }
              microsoftTeams.authentication.notifySuccess(user)
          })
          .catch(oError => {
            microsoftTeams.authentication.notifyFailure(oError)
          });
      }
```

How can i solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teams basically launches a login popup for you with `microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate`. As a result, even though you -see- a popup, you actually want to use a *redirect* flow. Please see here for a sample app illustrating this

https://github.com/pnp/teams-dev-samples/tree/master/samples/tab-sso

Comment: Hi, @Hilton, I've update my question can you say me where I've wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've changed my authorization flow and it's seems work fine.

Comment: Sorry I didn't have a chance to come back to you yet, been a busy day. Glad to hear you came right though. Do you want to "Edit" the answer above and post in your changes, so others can see in future if they need the same help? Just mark it as your edit or something